# Need Help Assigning ID Number to MySQL entry

Tags: php, mysql, sql, uniqueidentifier

I have created a MySQL database wherein users add information via PHP.  Each time a user adds information I want to assign that entry in the database a unique id number.  I would like the first number to be 10000.  Then then next entry should be 10001, then 10002 etc...

I have a general idea of how this can be done with PHP, but I am looking for some guidance on the most direct way to create this type of identifier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you would want to use the auto_increment with mysql. you can then use mysql_insertid() to retreive that id.

Answer (score 1):

@hookedonit is correct - you'll want to use auto_increment. Additionally, you'll need to set the starting count at 10000: `ALTER TABLE myTable AUTO_INCREMENT = 10000;`

Answer (score 1):

There is really no need to specify the id to start at a certain point. But if you are hell bent on it then you can set it using this...

```
ALTER TABLE tbl AUTO_INCREMENT = 100;
```

Also you should definitely let MySQL do the auto-incrementing. It saves resources and is very efficient. The create table should look something like this...

```
CREATE TABLE animals (
     id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     name CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;

INSERT INTO animals (name) VALUES
    ('dog'),('cat'),('penguin'),
    ('lax'),('whale'),('ostrich');
```

Ref: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html

Also, as @hookedonit states above, you can get the id of the last mysql insert with the php function mysql_insert_id (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php).

That should do ya!